# Sending mail with a Raspberry Pi hosted apache2/citadel server

Tags: php, apache, email, server, raspberry-pi

I have been running a web server off of my Raspberry Pi for a while now, getting to know HTML/CSS/JS/PHP. I wanted to learn how to send emails with the PHP mail() function from my website with a no-ip.com domain name. From my research, I realized that I needed to use SMTP, so I followed [this tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-email-server/) to setup a citadel mail server in addition to apache2 on my Pi. I got it "up and running" and I am able to send mail to and from users on the Citadel server, but I am not able to send mail to and from my personal Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send emails via smtp from google account you have to use googles paraneters for it, and for reciving emails from your host email to gmail well check your spam folder cos without proper registration of your emails domain name in mx record on dns server it will be concidered as spam by google. Hope this helped.